# Disable velocity.js animations for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, velocity.js

I have created a few Velocity.js animations that work well on a laptop using Chrome, Safari and Firefox, however, the animations sometimes crash or don't appear on my ipad2.  Due to the fact that it sometimes works, leads me to believe its my ipad2.  My question, is it possible to disable animations for ALL mobile devices, so they would display non-animated content?

Am assuming this would need to be done via JavaScript??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please set @ydaniv's reply as correct answer if appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `mock`, [see docs](http://julian.com/research/velocity/#mock), property of Velocity to force all animations' duration and delay to 0.
Just to demonstrate the idea, something like:

```
Velocity.mock = /iPad|iPod/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
```

But it will also be great if you could minimize the breaking animations into separate tests on jsFiddle/codepen/jsbin/etc and in case you see issues report them on the Velocity repo's issues tracker.